# Whats wrong with this regex logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to fetch the value after equal sign, its works but i am getting duplicated values , any idea whats wrong here?

```
 // Regex for finding a word after "=" sign
 var myregexpNew = /=(\S*)/g;
 // Regex for finding a word before "=" sign
 var mytype = /(\S*)=/g;
 //Setting data from Grid Column
 var strNew = "QCById=20";
 var matchNew = myregexpNew.exec(strNew);
 var newtype = mytype.exec(strNew);
 alert(matchNew);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vjjv0hv/

Comment: can u rewrite the logic?

Comment: Yes, I most certainly can, I won't however because this is not a "write code for me for free" site.

Comment: This is why you don't use alert for debugging. Open the browser's JS console and use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`exec` returns an array, the first element is the global match, the following ones are the submatches, that's why you get `["=20", "20"]` (using `console.log` here instead of `alert` would make it clearer what you get).

When looking for submatches and using `exec`, you're usually interested in the elements starting at index `1`.

Regarding the whole parsing, it's obvious there are better solution, like using only one regex with two submatches, but it depends on the real goal.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get duplicated values, you just get an array of a matched value and the captured text #1.

See [`RegExp#exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) help:

> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The **returned array** has the **matched text as the first item**, and **then one item for *each* capturing parenthesis** that matched containing the text that was captured.

Just use the `[1]` index to get the captured text only.

```js
var myregexpNew = /=(\S*)/g;
 var strNew = "QCById=20";
 var matchNew = myregexpNew.exec(strNew);
 if (matchNew) {
    console.log(matchNew[1]);
 }
```

To get values on both sides of `=`, you can use `/(\S*)=(\S*)/g` regex:

```js
var myregexpNew = /(\S*)=(\S*)/g;
var strNew = "QCById=20";
var matchNew = myregexpNew.exec(strNew);
if (matchNew) {
  console.log(matchNew[1]);
  console.log(matchNew[2]);
}
```

Also, you may want to add a  check to see if the captured values are not `undefined`/empty since `\S*` may capture an empty string. **OR** use `/(\S+)=(\S+)/g` regex that requires at least one non-whitespace character to appear before and after the `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can try without using Regex like this:

```js
var val = 'QCById=20';
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("=") + 1);
alert(myString);
```

Presently `exec` is returning you the matched value.

Comment: I commend you for a solution that doesn't use regular expressions, though please provide a solution that presents both the left and right-hand sides.

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP.exec(SOMETHING) returns an array (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). 
The first item in the array is the full match and the rest matches the parenthesized substrings.